# Dynamic div element height returns 0 after append

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, height

This is part of my code. It is inside a loop.

```
{//just to show its inside loop
ph = "<a id=\"" + id + "\" class=\"polaroid\" href=\"" + 
src + ".jpg\"><img src=\"" + src + "_q.jpg\"><p>" + item.title + "</p></a>";
$("#images").append(ph);
}
```

once it runs it appends ph to the images div, however when i call $("#images").height(); it returns 0. I have placed the call to height outside of the div, after all elements have been added and it still returns 0. any ideas would be appreciated. Also, "#images" is not dynamically created, just dynamically filled.

here is my html:

```
<body><div id="images"></div>
```

Comment: One possible reason is the `height` might have called before the images area loaded

Comment: if know height of images can add height attribute to image tag, or do it in css....should allow calcs before image loaded

Comment: I thought about that as well, so I called height after the loop(outside) but it still returns 0. when I check dom on inspector(firefox) it shows that all elements were added to #images, but still returns 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas, I figured it out, I added borders to all the elements(different colors) and I noticed that even though in the DOM it showed as the a tags being inside #images div, they were outside of #images borders, so I went to css and added overflow-y:auto, and they showed inside the border and now I get a value from $("#images).height(). thank you guys for your assistance, it allowed me to focus on the possible cause and eventual solution.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for(var i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        ph = "<img src=\"http://placekitten.com/g/30/30\" alt=\"\" />";
        $("#images").append(ph);
    }

    $("img").one('load', function() {
        $("#height").html($("#images").height());
    });
});
```

Comment: It still returns 0; but I noticed something odd, when I do $("#images a").height(); it returns me

Comment: It still returns 0; but I noticed something odd, when I do '$("#images a").height();' it returns 212 which is the height of one ph.